# How to interpret expectation of one specific observation of $u_i$, eg. $E[u_1|X]$?

Tags: jags

I'm a bit hung up on how to interpret the expectation of a single observation of the error term... especially in the context of the zero-conditional mean assumption.

If the true population model is given by $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i+u_i$, then our observed value for, say, $y_1$ is equal to $\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1+u_1$.

In expectation, we know that $E[u_i|X] = 0$ and $E[u_i] = 0$ due to the zero-conditional mean assumption, but how does this relate to our $u_1$ here? Is $E[u_1] = u_1$ since it is a constant?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you know how to answer this question for the model $y_i = u_i$?  If so, that will give you insight into your model, because they are not qualitatively different.

Comment: Hm...I suppose in that case each observation would just be some constant $u_1, u_2, ... u_n$. And the expectation of that constant would just be the constant itself. I just don't think I've ever seen the expectation of a specific value of the error term when analyzing an estimator, so difficult to wrap my head around.

Comment: You are interpreting $u_i$ in two inconsistent ways.  When you write $E[u_i],$ it is a random variable; when you refer to it as an observation, it is a number.  The intended meaning of something like $E[u_i\mid X]$ is as a *random variable.*  Compare the situation of flipping a coin with a chance $p$ of showing heads.  Even after flipping it and observing its outcome, the expectation of this coin remains $p$--it hasn't changed--even though the outcome is either $0$ or $1.$

Comment: Ah, the coin flip example is informative - thank you. So, regardless of any single realization of $u_i$, the expectation of that realization (under the zero-conditional mean assumption) remains the same as the expectation of the random variable in general.

Comment: I think you have the idea, but I would re-emphasize that the *realization* is fixed--it has no expectation.  Often we use different but parallel notation to distinguish random variables from their outcomes, such "$U_i$" for the random variable and "$u_i$" for a realization of it.  Then $E[U_i]$ is the expectation but usually it is not the case that $E[U_i]=u_i.$

Comment: Unfortunately that has confused me a bit further, but I do really appreciate your follow up. 

If I'm analyzing the unbiasedness an estimator $\hat\beta_1 = \beta_1+\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=2}^{n} \frac{1}{x_i-x_1}(u_i-u_1)$, where $u_1$ is the error associated with $y_1$ in the population (e.g. $y_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 +u_1$) and I want to derive the expectation conditional on $x$. Under zero-conditional mean, I'm conformable saying the $u_i$ term will drop to zero. But I'm still very unsure how that lingering $u_1$ can be interpreted. Does it just remain a constant w. no expectation?

Comment: Your expression for $\hat \beta_1$ is not an estimator because it relies on information you don't have: namely, precisely what $u_1$ is.  Whether you are referring to a random variable or its realization is immaterial, because in either case you don't know it.

Comment: That is an important point, thanks. I suppose in that case, when I plugged in $\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + u_1$ for $y_1$ when constructing my estimator, I introduced information I don't have. Perhaps the key implication of zero-conditional mean then is that for my observed $y_1$ there is no observed $u_1$, there is just $\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1$. I'll have to do some thinking, but that result would simplify things significantly.

Comment: @whuber would $E[y_1|X] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1$ be a more appropriate way to express the expected value of some random first observation of the dependent variable, $y_1$ as opposed to $y_i$,  in our sample given the corresponding $x_1$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're comparing it to, but that expression is correct because it follows from the zero-mean assumption about $u_1$ and the linearity of expectation.